# in JavaScript,how do I just get the function I evoked to fire instead of other functions as well?

Tags: javascript

```js
function haveOne() {

  document.querySelector(".spiderSetEverest").scrollIntoView();

var synth = new Tone.Synth().toMaster();


synth.triggerAttackRelease('a3', '2n')
}

function haveTwo() {
  document.querySelector(".aboutUs").scrollIntoView();}

function haveThree() {
  document.querySelector(".gallery").scrollIntoView();

}

function haveFour() {
  document.querySelector(".contactUs").scrollIntoView();
}


function haveFive() {
  document.querySelector(".crusherDiv").scrollIntoView();
}


function haveSix() {

  document.querySelector(".programming").scrollIntoView();
}


function haveSeven() {

  document.querySelector(".experiments").scrollIntoView();
}


function haveEight() {

  document.querySelector(".startUpTechnologies").scrollIntoView();
}



function haveNine() {
  document.querySelector(".recipes").scrollIntoView();}



function revealPoolTables() {
  document.querySelector("#poolTables").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function revealPokerTables() {
  document.querySelector("#pokerTables").style.visibility = "visible"
}

function revealScorpianPool() {
  document.querySelector("#scorpianPool").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.querySelector("#poolTables").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function revealCrowAndTurtlePool() {
  document.querySelector("#crowAndTurtlePool").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.querySelector("#poolTables").style.visibility = "hidden"
}

function revealGreenNodePoker() {
  document.querySelector("#GreenNodePoker").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.querySelector("#pokerTables").style.visibility = "hidden"
}

function revealOwlColadePoker() {
  document.querySelector("#OwlcoladePoker").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.querySelector("#pokerTables").style.visibility = "hidden"
}



function alertSeven() {
  window.location.href = 'donationportal.php';
}

function backToGallery() {
  location.reload();
    document.querySelector(".gallery").scrollIntoView();
}

function SevenLab(){var frequencyLab = document.createElement('div');document.querySelector(".experiments").appendChild(frequencyLab);frequencyLab.setAttribute('class',"frequencyLab");frequencyLab.style="box-sizing:border-box;border:3px solid green; height:400px; width:400px;background-color:yellow;position:absolute:top:33%;left:33%;";frequencyLab.innerHTML='<button onclick="expelmentCastleLab()">LAB</button>'}
function expelmentCastleLab(){var carrotsThroughTheStatistics = document.createElement('div');document.querySelector(".experiments").appendChild(carrotsThroughTheStatistics);carrotsThroughTheStatistics.setAttribute('class','heyForest');carrotsThroughTheStatistics.style="box-sizing:border-box;border:3px solid green; height:300px;width:300px;background-color:#FFaaff;position:absolute;top:45%;left:45%;color:orange;font-size:2 em;)";carrotsThroughTheStatistics.innerHTML='<div onmouseover="raiseStacks()" id = "freezerBurn" style="box-sizing:border-box;border:3px solid green; height: 750px; width: 750px;background-image:url(\'../images(1)/chessBoard3.jpg\')">hey</div>';}
function raiseStacks(){document.querySelector(".heyForest").style.transform="matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,.75)";document.querySelector(".heyForest").style.backgroundColor="red";document.querySelector(".heyForest").setAttribute("onmouseover","setTimeout()")}
function setTimeout(){location.assign("theDutchLab.php");}
```

```css
#video{         z-index: 2;
                box-sizing: border-box; 
                margin: 0;
                border: 3px solid green;
                padding:200px; 
                height: 700px;
                width: 700px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 35%;
                left:35%;
                background-image: url( "../images(1)/chessBoard3.jpg");
                color: orange;
                font-size: 3em;}
#OwlcoladePoker{box-sizing: border-box; 
                margin: 10px;
                border: 3px solid green;
                height: 800px;
                width: 2000px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 15%;
                left:25%;
                background-image: url( \"../images(1)/chessBoard3.jpg\");
                color: orange;
                font-size: 3em;
                visibility: hidden;}
#GreenNodePoker{box-sizing: border-box; 
                margin: 10px;
                border: 3px solid green;
                height: 800px;
                width: 2000px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 15%;
                left:25%;
                background-image: url("../images(1)/chessBoard3.jpg");
                color: orange;
                font-size: 3em;
                visibility: hidden;}
#pokerTables{box-sizing: border-box;    
                margin: 10px;
                border: 3px solid green;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 5%;
                left:25%;
                background-color: orange;
                color: orange;
                font-size: 3em;
                visibility: hidden;}
#poolTables{box-sizing: border-box; 
                margin: 10px;
                border: 3px solid green;
                height: 200px;
                width: 200px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 5%;
                left:25%;
                background-color: orange;
                color: orange;
                font-size: 3em;
                visibility: hidden;}
#scorpianPool{box-sizing: border-box;   
                margin: 10px;
                border: 3px solid green;
                height: 800px;
                width: 2000px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 15%;
                left:25%;
                background-image: url( "../images(1)/chessBoard3.jpg");
                color: orange;
                font-size: 3em;
                visibility: hidden;}
#crowAndTurtlePool{box-sizing: border-box;  
                margin: 10px;
                border: 3px solid green;
                height: 800px;
                width: 2000px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 15%;
                left:25%;
                background-image: url("../images(1)/chessBoard3.jpg");
                color: orange;
                font-size: 3em;
                visibility: hidden;}

#Layer_1{
    z-index: -2;
}
.TopOfBody {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 3%;
  left: 10%;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  color: red;
}
.sessionInsert_02 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 30%;
  border: 4px solid orange;
  color: red;
}
.whybacktosummitButton_01 {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 55%;
}
.spiderseteverestLink {
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 15%;
  left: 25%;
  background: black;
}
.whybacktosummitButton {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22%;
  left: 22%;
}
.crusherButton {
 
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 55%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.crusher {
  
    
}
.crusherDiv {
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 3000px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 3006px;
    top: 10%;
}

.aboutUs {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 3000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 170%;
}
.gallery {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 3000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 205%;
}
.contactUs {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 3000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 240%;
}
.programming {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 3000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 275%;
}
.experiments {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 3000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 310%;
}
.startUpTechnologies {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 3000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 345%;
}
.recipes {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 3000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 380%;
}


.logo {
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11%;
  left: 40%;
}
.blogDiv {
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 5em;
  border: none;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  left: 1%;
  background-image: url("../images(1)/bullface.png");
}
.three {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 10px dashed pink;
    font-stretching:extra-expanded;

transform: scaleX(3);
    }
.liNoListType1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  top:1%;
    
    left:4%;
  width: 50%;
}
.liNoListType3 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  top:7%;
    
    left:4%;
  width: 50%;
}
.liNoListType2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  
  height: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  top:14%;
    
    left:4%;
  width: 50%;
}
.liNoListType4 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  top:21%;
    
    left:4%;
  width: 50%;
}
.liNoListType5 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  top:28%;
    
    left:4%;
  width: 50%;
}
.liNoListType6 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  top:35%;
    
    left:4%;
  width: 50%;
}
.liNoListType7 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  top:42%;
    
    left:4%;
  width: 50%;
}
.liNoListType8 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  top:49%;
    
    left:4%;
  width: 50%;
}
.liNoListType9 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
 top:56%;
    
    left:4%;
  width: 50%;
}
.liNoListType10 {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  top:62%;
  left:4%;
  width: 50%;
}
polygon {
  stroke: black;
}
.header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 1200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left:700px;
  font: 200 35px/1.3 'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: orange;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
article {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 1200px;
  width: 1800px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 210px;
  left: 210px;
}
aside {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.animatedSVG {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: green;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2500px;
  left: 201px;
  opacity: .7;
  z-index: 0;
}
.footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: green;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2500px;
  left: 201px;
  background-image: url("../images(1)/mountain.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: .7;
  z-index: 1;
}
.spiderArchiveButton {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 200%;
  opacity: 100%;
    }
.one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 18%;
  font: 200 35px/1.3 'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.svgthree {
  z-index: 1;
}
.TheD {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: beige;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 75%;
  left: 1%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 13px dashed orange;
  font: 200 35px/1.3 'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3000px;
  width: 3000px;
background-image: url( "../images(1)/4x/OctagonalBackGroundRSE1@4x.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    

}
.spiderSetEverest {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 25px;
  height: 3000px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 135%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://tonejs.github.io/build/Tone.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="../JavaScript/tone.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ready Set Everest</title>
<link href="../CSS/readySetEverestWebsite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="video">
  <video width="500" height="500" controls>
  <source src="../images(1)/Dirty Vegas - Days Go By (Official Video).mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>


<header class="header">Hello Welcome to Ready Set Everest. Please browse the site, login at the bottom of the page and check out our affiliate, Spider Set Everest.If you have any trouble with the page, simply refresh the page. The sites run the best using the zoom in/out on your browser. (zoom+/-) </header>
<div class="logo"><img src="../images(1)/ReadySetEverestTextLogo.png" width="191" height="115" alt="7"/></div>
<aside> <a href="pokerTryOne.php">
  <button class="three">
  <h1>Poker Site</h1>
  </button>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li class="liNoListType1">
      <button  onClick="haveOne()">Spider Set Everest</button>
    </li>
    <li class="liNoListType2">
      <button  onClick="haveTwo()">About Us</button>
    </li>
    <li class="liNoListType3">
      <button  onClick="haveThree()">Gallery</button>
    </li>
    <li class="liNoListType4">
      <button  onClick="haveFour()">Contact</button>
    </li>
    <li class="liNoListType5">
      <button  onClick="haveFive()">Plastic Consilidation Machine</button>
    </li>
    <li class="liNoListType6">
      <button  onClick="haveSix()">Programming</button>
    </li>
    <li class="liNoListType7">
      <button  onClick="haveSeven()">Experiments</button>
    </li>
    <li class="liNoListType8">
      <button  onClick="haveEight()">Start Up Technologies</button>
    </li>
    <li class="liNoListType9">
      <button  onClick="haveNine()">Recipes</button>
    </li>
    <li class="liNoListType10">
      <a href="toDo.php"><button">To Do</button></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="donationportal.php">
      <button class="TheD">
      <h1>D</h1>
      </button>
      </a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>

<footer class="footer">
  <?php

  require "sessionInsert.php";
  ?>
  <div class="sessionInsert_02">
    <?php
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'id' ] ) ) {
      echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged out!</p>';
    } else if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'id' ] ) ) {
      echo '<p class="login-status">You are logged in!</p>';
    }
    ?>
  </div>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small> </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Join mailing List</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <button class ="MakeItSnowButton" onClick="makeItSnow()">Make It Snow</button>
</footer>
<div class="animatedSVG">
  <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 780.48 752.52">
    <defs>
      <style>
.cls-1{fill:#fff;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;transition: transform 3s;}
</style>
    </defs>
    <title>svgSnow</title>
    <rect class="cls-1" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="751.52" height="751.52"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseOne" cx="113.32" cy="121.26" rx="21.33" ry="51.33"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseTwo" cx="473.98" cy="171.59" rx="32.67" ry="50.33"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseThree" cx="231.32" cy="275.26" rx="35.33" ry="53.33"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseFour" cx="465.32" cy="491.26" rx="33.33" ry="60"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseFive" cx="678.65" cy="325.76" rx="36" ry="50.5"/>
    <circle class="cls-1" id="CircleOne" cx="363.82" cy="344.42" r="31.83"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseSix" cx="345.23" cy="120.76" rx="18.58" ry="50.83"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseSeven" cx="612.65" cy="98.59" rx="35.33" ry="60.67"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseEight" cx="747.32" cy="61.92" rx="32.67" ry="53.33"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1"  id="ellipseNine" cx="66.65" cy="450.59" rx="25.33" ry="67.33"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseTen" cx="262.65" cy="536.59" rx="18.67" ry="45.33"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseEleven" cx="149.32" cy="654.59" rx="46.67" ry="40.67"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseTwelve" cx="203.32" cy="401.92" rx="12.67" ry="40"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseThirteen" cx="397.32" cy="614.59" rx="12" ry="32.67"/>
    <ellipse class="cls-1" id="ellipseFourteen" cx="655.32" cy="553.26" rx="23.33" ry="55.33"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<article class="article">
  <h1>
    <div class="blogDiv">
      <p><a style="color: orange;" href="https://66a8090b7e6cb64f2254b14c7f6a4d3a.blogspot.com">Blog</a></p>
    </div>
  </h1>
  <div class="one"><img src="../images(1)/ReadySetEverestPicLogo.png" width="1003" height="1050" alt="7"/></div>
</article>
   
    

<div class="spiderSetEverest">
  <h1>Spider Set Everest</h1>
  <h2><img src="../images(1)/spider8normalorangelegs.png" width="300" height="336" alt=""/></h2>
  <div class="spiderseteverestLink">
    <p><?php echo "<a style='color:red' href=SpiderSetEverest.php>SpiderSetEverest.com</a>"?></p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p>
    <button class="whybacktosummitButton" onClick="backtoLeft()">Back To Summit</button>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="aboutUs">
  <h1>About Us</h1>
  <div class="aboutUsHighlights">
    <h2>HighLights</h2>
    <li style="list-style-type: none"> This company will produce and direct products towards a digital domain. It will also pertain to some retail markets. Through technologies, our goal is to make the best solutions to common problems to make them less common. </li>
    <ul>
      <li style="list-style-type: none">2</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      <button onClick="backtoLeft()">Back To Summit</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <h1>Gallery</h1>
  
  <ul>
    <li style="list-style-type: none">
        <p><button onClick="revealPoolTables()">Pool Table Designs</button></p>
        <button onClick="revealPokerTables()">Poker Table Designs</button>
        
        <!--Pool tables-->
        <p><div id="poolTables"><button onClick="revealScorpianPool()">Scorpian Pool Table</button><button onClick="revealCrowAndTurtlePool()">Crow and Turtle</button></div></p>
        
        <div id="scorpianPool"><button onClick="alertSeven()" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1; top: 45%; left:35%; color: orange;height: 200px;width: 200px; font-size: 2em;">Buy</button><button onClick="backToGallery()" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1; top: 65%; left:55%; color: orange;height: 200px;width: 200px; font-size:1em;">Back To gallery</button></div>
        <div id="crowAndTurtlePool"><button onClick="alertSeven()" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1; top: 45%; left:35%; color: orange;height: 200px;width: 200px; font-size: 2em;">Buy</button><button onClick="backToGallery()" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1; top: 65%; left:55%; color: orange;height: 200px;width: 200px; font-size:1em;">Back To gallery</button></div>
    <!--Poker Tables-->
    <p><div id="pokerTables"><button onClick="revealGreenNodePoker()">Green Node Poker Table</button><button onClick="revealOwlColadePoker()">Owlcolade Poker Table</button></div></p>
        
        <div id="GreenNodePoker"><button onClick="alertSeven()" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1; top: 45%; left:35%; color: orange;height: 200px;width: 200px; font-size: 2em;">Buy</button><button onClick="backToGallery()" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1; top: 65%; left:55%; color: orange;height: 200px;width: 200px; font-size:1em;">Back To gallery</button></div>
        <div id="OwlcoladePoker"><button onClick="alertSeven()" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1; top: 45%; left:35%; color: orange;height: 200px;width: 200px; font-size: 2em;">Buy</button><button onClick="backToGallery()" style="position: absolute;z-index: 1; top: 65%; left:55%; color: orange;height: 200px;width: 200px; font-size:1em;">Back To gallery</button></div>
    
    
    
    
    
      </li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    <button onClick="backtoLeft()">Back To Summit</button>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="programming">
  <h1>Programming
    <div class="PokerSiteCommentThread">
      <p>Would like to make a poker website with a basic 52 card poker. I would like to use the fisher-yates algorithm.
        //Chille out on some chili this chili is not ready yet, it ought to go live within 3-16 months//
        If possible, If I can with help, constructive criticsm through commenting will help me construct the poker site. It ought to be using the fisher-yates algorithm, with the deck shuffled between each delt player, and also between the flop, the turn, and the river. Based bets before the flop, between the turns and rivers, and also before the deal in the way of big and small blinds. I currently have a a sample of the website you can try. There are currently four players, and an additional UserPlayer. </p>
    </div>
  </h1>
  <p>
    <button onClick="backtoLeft()">Back To Summit</button>
  </p>
</div>
   
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/readySEPageButtons.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/crusherMachine.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/backToLeft.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/SimpleBlog.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/makeItSnow.js"></script>
<?php
// And just like we include the header from a separate file, we do the same with the footer.
require "loginfooter.php";
?>
```

After I click the aside button(Spider Set Everest) and the tone plays fired from the function haveOne() in the javascript file, the function at the bottom of the javascript document fires as well and redirects the page. I just want the haveOne() function to fire, not any of the other functions on the js file. Does This have something to do with the tone itself? Why does the last function on the page fire if I did not call it?

Comment: there seems to be a number of issues: you have a function called `setTimeout` which shadows the same function as the [window setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method - are you trying to override this method?; `<button>` elements can't be descendants of `<a>` elements; your `<button>` tag in the `liNoListType10` list item is malformed (you have a quote after the word button in the start tag); you have several invalid descendants of heading elements. I would recommend cleaning up your code and markup and seeing if the issue remains

Comment: @AndroidNoobie to the last piece advice you mentioned,”several invalid descendants of heading elements”, do you mean <h1> tags with tags within them? Do you have any examples of places where explanation is given of why not to do this? Thanks

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I guess it’s just as easy to put a div within a div, just wondering if there was a firm explanation, like the formatting of the <h1> tag that is predefined is diminished in some way.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie otherwise it was the setTimeout function that needed changing, thank you.